# Java Phone Book won't accept input from 2 strings

Tags: java

This is a project I am working on for a java phone book. I was trying to compile, but when I try to add the second string, it just skips right over it.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    HashMap<String, String> PhoneBook = new HashMap<String, String>();
        while (true == true){
            System.out.println("Main Menu: ");
            System.out.println("1. Add to phonebook");
            System.out.println("2. Remove from phonebook");
            System.out.println("3. Read the phonebook");
            System.out.println("4. Clear entire phonebook");
            int choice = s.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the name of the person: ");
                String name = s.nextLine();
                PhoneBook.put(name, "Blah");
                System.out.println("Please enter the number of the person: ");
                String number = s.nextLine();
                PhoneBook.put(name, number);

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this has to do with that you are trying to insert duplicate entry

```
if (choice == 1) {
   System.out.println("Please enter the name of the person: ");
   String name = s.nextLine();
   PhoneBook.put(name, "Blah"); //first entry of name
   System.out.println("Please enter the number of the person: ");
   String number = s.nextLine();
   PhoneBook.put(name, number); //second duplicate entry!

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A) it seems inefficient to put a key with an invalid value to a hash map and afterward rewrite the value.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    HashMap<String, String> PhoneBook = new HashMap<String, String>();
        while (true == true){
            System.out.println("Main Menu: ");
            System.out.println("1. Add to phonebook");
            System.out.println("2. Remove from phonebook");
            System.out.println("3. Read the phonebook");
            System.out.println("4. Clear entire phonebook");
            int choice = s.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the name of the person: ");
                String name = s.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter the number of the person: ");
                String number = s.nextLine();
                PhoneBook.put(name, number);

            }

    }

}
```

B) I think this should help you resolve the issue, but if it does not please let me know and I can re-edit my answer. I think you just put the value to the same key, and that is why you think you are not getting the 2nd value